# Bitcode signature failure in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, bitcode

I updated Xcode to the last version, and now when I'm trying to compile the project I'm getting an error "Invalid bitcode signature", hovewer, the bitcode for my project is disabled. How can I fix it? What should I change to sign my bitcode correctly?

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProjectName' do

pod 'Realm'
pod 'CorePlot'
pod 'GoogleMaps'

end
```

I checked already, everything is fine with it.

Comment: Clean derived data.

Comment: I did it firstly, doesn't work

Comment: We need more information. I suspect one of the used dependencies is causing the problem.

Comment: When looking for debug help you need to provide the Podfile.lock, not the Podfile. And the exact version of Xcode preferably.

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure if you have the same situation with me. I only have this issue when I tried to test with iPhone device. It turns out that the debug configuration with Build Active Architecture Only is set to NO. After I set to YES, I can test with my iPhone.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head against the wall with XCode 8.3 and 8.3.1 all complaining about "Invalid bitcode signature" until I changed this.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying to work this out for ages - I had bitcode turned off and this error still came up until I set Build Active Architecture to YES

Comment: My savior! Hero without cap!

Comment: How come you don't get the same error when archiving the app for publication ? `Build Active Architecture Only` is still NO for Release mode.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this error, but it happened only when building for an iOS 10.3 iPad (despite working on an iOS 10.3 iPhone and an iOS 11.0 iPad, and all the iOS 10.3 and 11.0 simulators). Through painful process of elimination (and creating a new project from scratch), I found that my Cocoapods weren't at fault, nor was my code signing settings, nor my AppExtension, nor my tests, nor my 'build for active architecture only' setting, nor any build setting related to the term 'bitcode'.

In my setup, I had a C++ Xcode project nested within my main Swift/iOS Xcode project. Because it was never intended specifically for use in iOS, the "iOS Deployment target" had never been set (it was left on 'default'). Upon setting it explicitly to 10.3, it worked without complaint.

**Nested C++ app's project settings** (set iOS deployment target to the lowest iOS version you support):

[image: Nested C++ app's project settings]

**Nested C++ app's target settings** (for reference):

[image: Nested C++ app's target settings]

Comment: Awesome, tried everything finally got it working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jas_meet Glad that I could save someone else from this plight! One of the hardest errors I've ever had to track down (especially given how slow build times are).

Comment: I had this same issue... project was working on an iPhone with iOS 10.2 but not one with 10.3.3. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks so much, this saved me. I didn't even realise the app I'm working on had a nested project - it's a cordova app.

Answer (score 3):

If you using pod then please check the version of all libraries, some library may be not supporting in new version , you have to update pod files for that library.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying to build for a device with an iOS version lower than the deployment target.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of problem came up when I linked a new static library project to my workspace. In order to solve it I tried to set both the Build Active Architecture Only and the Bitcode settings of the library to NO but no luck. Then I got across the thing that the library's Deployment Target was set to 11.0 as Xcode set the latest value to all new projects. After fixing the setting to 5.0 the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

On my case problem occured because of I was using a 3rd party static library with different files for each architecture

I fixed the problem by removing binaries of invalid architectures.
Instead I added a multi-arch [FAT binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) for the 3rd party static library

Hope helps

Answer (score 1):

For my case, the solution was removing a c++ library.

Comment: It's possible that setting the iOS deployment target, rather than removing the C++ library altogether, would have sufficed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46864401/5951226

Answer (score 1):

I found that my issue was with using 'Modules'.

Just turned off modules (had to update some header files), but that resolved my issue.

[Enable Modules In Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6BnS.png)

Comment: Don't know your case but disabling modules is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the widget included in the project was causing the bitcode error.

I changed my pod file from this:

```
target "App" do
    pod 'A'
    pod 'B'
end

target "App Widget" do
    pod 'A'
end
```

to this:

```
target "App" do
    pod 'A'
    pod 'B'

    target "App Widget" do
        pod 'A'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, most answers recommend a workaround whereby you clean your Xcode workspace/project, close Xcode, delete your `Derived Data` folder (this is kept in the root directory of your project by default), then finally re-open your project.

However, the above steps may not work for you. This is a hint that your project structure is in error.

When the bitcode intermediary representation of your project was released with iOS 9.0, it was done so on the provision that your entire project, *including dependencies*, either totally agree to use bitcode or not. From my experience, it is vital to work through all of your `Pods` and included `Libraries/Frameworks` and ensure they all use the same setting; either **Yes** or **No**. By default, this selection is **Yes**.

If a single dependency does not match the intended bitcode setting, this error can be thrown.

When sanity checking your dependencies and overarching project, it is important to note that there is a `Use Bitcode` setting for **both** the Project and the Target settings, so be sure to check both perspectives of the Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding static library . I created fat binary of the same library including all architectures and included in my project. This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am Using **Cordova Project**. While building it with Xcode had the same issue and Resolved by Removing and Adding the IOS platform.

```
cordova platform remove ios

cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoa pods then do "pod update"

Answer (score 0):

Targets -> Build Settings ->Build Active Architecture Only

Debug -> YES 
Release -> **NO to  YES**

I face the same problem only on archiving the app.

Who can tell me the reason? You can teach all developers. It's awesome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me. First, try to remove all pod using terminal command **pod deintegrate** and then reinstall pod using terminal command **pod install**.

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur when building for the simulator if including a framework built for ARM only (and I assume vice-versa as well).