# linker command failed with exit code 1 in old source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bitcode

I have an old project that was developed few years ago. Now when I compile it in latest Xcode 8.3.1 than its giving me some errors. I also googled it but didn't get success.
[image]

[image]

Here is the screenshot of logs so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcode signature failure in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180258/bitcode-signature-failure-in-xcode)

Comment: please have a look into updated screenshot.

Comment: First time when I compiled my code, it was giving error of "libThree20Network-Xcode3.2.5.a" not found in simulators folder but right now simple "linker command failed with exit code 1" error.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for the original question "BitCode Signature failure":**

Possible duplicate of the question:
[Bitcode signature failure in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180258/bitcode-signature-failure-in-xcode)

Please find the answer there :)

**Answer for duplicate symbols error:**

Possible duplicate of the question:
[duplicate symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427024/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Please find the answer there :)