# Reinstalled pods and get invalid bitcode signature error. why?

Tags: xcode, clang, cocoapods, bitcode

I installed the pods again on my xcode project and i get this :

```
error: Invalid bitcode signature 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Also, i tried to clean and build, but nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcode signature failure in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180258/bitcode-signature-failure-in-xcode)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346793/invalid-bitcode-signature-on-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just opened terminal and use `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`. If you use `pod update` or `install` doesn't works, without using `pod deintegrate` before.