# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error & Invalid bitcode signature

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've tried just about everything I can get my hands on, but my iOS app just won't build. Here is a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

The Cocoapod I'm trying to use is EZUIKit. It installs fine, but once installed I get these two error messages when trying to build.

Comment: [Invalid bitcode signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180258/bitcode-signature-failure-in-xcode)

Comment: Tried all of those, nothing worked :/ thanks though. I'll keep at it. Is there any chance it's a problem with the Pod itself?

Comment: Yesterday I also got the same error, there is a pod file that generated but not available in the bundle. You can deintegrate the pods and re-install and check whther you got same error or not. This error can be happened just because of framework not available in binary, so keep it check too.

Comment: I've deintegrated & reinstalled multiple times; I also set "enable bitcode" to no; still, nothing.

Comment: Which pod u r using, let me try the same pod and check whther im getting the issue or not.

Comment: "EZUIKit" I've tried to run a simple project with it on 2 machines and got the same error message on both, although the fact that they have nearly identical dev environments may be the cause of that.

Comment: I tried this pod and got same error, I think there is issue in pod and its documentation is in chinese type lang and unable to understand. Now I can only suggest you **NOT TO USE** . Now its all up to you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you there...trying to link statically now, hope that goes well